# Will Materialized view refresh fail if I alter base table to add column

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a huge table in Oracle and there is a Materialized View which refreshes on demand to get data from this table.

This refresh takes upto an hour. While the refresh is on, If we add a column to the base table i.e. run a DDL statement on base table, will the refresh still work? Or it will fail midway?

Comment: I don't know. However, as you refresh it *on demand*, then don't *demand* it until you add the column.

Comment: Though I am not sure about Oracle but I have seen in other DBMS that it will not allow you to alter your table until the materialized view is enabled. So please check Oracle might not also allow to alter your table while the materialized view is being refreshed.